# Is it necessary to create Task for Product Backlog Item or Bug?

Tags: azure-devops, workitem

Using Scrum Process Template in VSTS, both Product Backlog Items (PBI) and Bugs can have a number of Tasks assigned to them.

[image: VSTS processes]

Assuming simple scenario, where a PBI or Bug requires only one Task, do I need to create that Task in order to not loose any functionality further in the process? For simple PBIs and Bugs it looks like an unnecessary redundant work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, For simple PBIs and Bugs about unnecessary redundant work, there's no need to add a task. 
TFS provide the feature to link Tasks to PBI and Bugs. You could link tasks to them or not link, it doesn't force every PBI to link one or more tasks. This depends on your situation and scenario. And some simple PBIs that maybe very easy and only one task could achieve, there's no need to add more tasks.